# AccessControlException when i'm trying to run applet on jsp

Tags: java, security, jsp, jdbc, applet

I'm getting exception when i'm running my jsp page, in which i've embedded the applet

my jsp file code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
      <applet code="myform.applet" archive="applet.jar,ojdbc14.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**applet.jar** in which i've made one class, in which i'm trying to retrieve the database values from the oracle database table.

and exception through

```
Exception in thread "thread applet-myform.applet-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at myform.applet.init(applet.java:28)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:316)
    ... 5 more
```

I searched everywhere, but didn't get my solution and somewhere it has been explained in a broad manner, which i can't understand as a newbie. Please help me, i'm stuck with this problem since last two days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets run in secured environment. The SecurityManager controls what applet is doing and does not allow it to perform forbidden operations.

From stack trace we can see that Oracle driver tries to access system class loader that is forbidden for applet.

You have generally 3 ways to solve this problem.

1. Sign your applet. In this case you will be able to do everything. But be careful. The next problem will be that the driver will not be able to connect to DB because of firewall between your client's browser and server where Oracle is running.
2. Develop your client as regular application and use Java web start to start it. User can still start the application by clicking link in his web browser but he will get fully functional application (exactly as in case of signed applet). The firewall problem is still relevant here.
3. Create 3 tier application. The frontend may be either applet or thin client. The business logic may be a simple web application that expose RESTful API and connects to DB to retrieve and store data.

Comment: so, third option will be the best...in your opinion..??

Comment: Yes, I believe that the third option is so called "right" solution. The choice depends on other requirements, your skills and time you have to develop the full solution.

Comment: I would say your option 3 is preferred. Generally, you want to avoid exposing your database to anything but your application-servers.